# How to Access an array Struct Inside an array Struct in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to access the variable name of the Reservation struct like this hotel[SomeIndex].reservations[AnotherIndex].name but it's not working.

How can I access those variables to fill the structure?

PS: It compiles,but it shows in debugger Segmentation Fault.

```
struct Reservation{
string name;
};

struct Hotel {
string name;
Reservation *reservations;
};



int main()
{
    struct Hotel *hotel;
    hotel = new Hotel[20];
    hotel->reservations=new Reservation[10];


    hotel[9].name="Olympus Plaza";
    hotel[9].reservations[5].name="John Doe";

    cout<<"Hotel: "<<hotel[9].name<<" Name: "<<hotel[9].reservations[5].name<<endl;

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is the third line of `main()` where you allocate reservations without dereferencing it. You should specify which `hotel` you want to allocate 10 `Reservation` structs, Then later you access `hotel[9].reservations[5]` that you haven't allocated.

Comment: Also you should be using std::vector (or std::array since you seem to be using fixed sizes), but at the very least do the allocations in the constructor of the struct (this would avoid the problem Frecklefoot mentioned, since each Hotel would have allocated its resources, which you forgot to do).

Comment: Thanks @Frecklefoot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not correctly initialize the reservations. Doing this correctly with raw pointers is hard and error-prone, and absolutely not recommended in C++.

First of all, use an `std::vector<Hotel>` instead of a raw array `Hotel *`. Vectors are the normal C++ "array" objects.

You can then replace the raw `Reservation *` pointer inside the `Hotel` struct with a `std::vector<Reservation>` as well.

This makes it much easier to fix the actual error: The missing initialization.

What you did was create 20 hotels, then create 10 reservations *for the first hotel*! Then you try to access reservations for the 9th hotel, where there is an uninitialized pointer which points to random data. This means the behaviour is undefined: In this case, a segmentation fault is the way that your system shows you that you are accessing data which doesn't belong to you.

You need a loop to create reservations for each of the hotels, or if you just want to create reservations in the 9th hotel, you need to specify its index.

Using `std::vector` is very simple:

```
#include <vector>

struct Reservation {
    string name;
};

struct Hotel {
    string name;
    vector<Reservation> reservations;
    // if you have no "using namespace std", then it's "std::vector".
};
```

And then you can just create reservations for the correct hotel:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Hotel> hotel(20);
    hotel[9].reservations.resize(10);

    hotel[9].name="Olympus Plaza";
    hotel[9].reservations[5].name="John Doe";

    cout<<"Hotel: "<<hotel[9].name<<" Name: "<<hotel[9].reservations[5].name<<endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hotel->reservations=new Reservation[10];` is equivalent to `hotel[0].reservations=new Reservation[10];`. You've initialised `hotel[0]` but none of the other elements of `hotel` - specifically not `hotel[9]`.

It looks like what you need is to define constructors for `Hotel` and `Reservation` that initialise all their members to well-defined values.

And I would strongly suggest you use `std::vector` rather than raw arrays; arrays are an advanced feature and very easy to go wrong with.

Comment: Minor nitpick, I wouldn't say raw arrays is an advanced feature, but an error prone one.

Comment: @Borgleader That's a perfectly reasonable opinion. But I prefer my way of putting it - they should be taught late in a C++ course (if at all), they should be used only when the more obvious mechanisms aren't suitable, and the semantics are tricky at best.